# Gantt Chart showing small size

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, css, gantt-view

I have created a page layout with 5 tab and each tab has a webpart zone than I added webpart on each tab.
However some time gantt chart showing small size and some time with proper size.

I have got some solution that says it is because of bootstrap but I have removed bootstrap but it still have same issue.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using IE or Chrome, use developer tools to inspect the element. From there you will understand which CSS is getting applied on that web part, modify that CSS to your needs.

Comment: As it is out  of chart so it generating lots of div with lots of inline css , it is very difficult to detect ..i am trying since morning..:)

Comment: Suggestion: Its not a SharePoint issue, work with a web designer and he will tell you which css is getting applied.

Comment: Also, try doing it in OOB pages and an application page. That should give you a better picture.

Answer (score 0):

Yooo, I got the solution.
It was due to multiple web part with web part zone on the page so it takes the time to load the web part when we change the tab.
So,
I have set that web part as a first default tab as it will always load first.
[image]